# How to refer to a particular IFrame when calling a C# method registered with RegisterJsObject from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe, cefsharp

I want to be able to, given any random web page, tell a C# method in an object registered using [RegisterJsObject](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_RegisterJsObject.htm) to "select" a particular frame. What I mean by "selecting" a frame is to keep a reference to the corresponding [IFrame](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_IFrame.htm) so that all subsequent calls to [EvaluateScriptAsync](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_EvaluateScriptAsync.htm) are made on this frame.

I need to do this from JavaScript because I already wrote a set of tools in JavaScript to interact and select elements on the page (like Chrome Developer Tools). So all I want to do is be able to, from a JavaScript code that runs on the window that contains the frame (that I'll inject dynamically into the page), call a method in my C# object and tell it to "select *that* particular frame". I just have no idea how tell my C# code which [IFrame](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_IFrame.htm) I want to select.

Since these are random pages I cannot rely on IDs or frame names. Also, I don't know if there is a way to get the [Identifier](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IFrame_Identifier.htm) assigned to an iframe by CefSharp from JavaScript. I've also tried to assign a unique name to my iframe from JavaScript and then refer to it by name, but the [Name](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IFrame_Name.htm) property of `IFrame` doesn't get updated after I rename the frame from JavaScript.

The only approach that seems to work is by doing `someFrame.focus()` (where `someFrame` is the iframe element I want to select) from JavaScript and then getting the [`FocusedFrame`](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IBrowser_FocusedFrame.htm) from C#. The problem with this is that it doesn't seem reliable at all. Some pages could have scripts that prevent the frame from keeping focus.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: _I want to be able to visually select the iframe in which scripts will run_ what does this mean? what I understand is user will manually select `IFrame` to execute script? If I am wrong then I would like to know what will be the criteria to _tell "select that particular iframe"_. I mean their should be a criteria to select a IFrame from 10 IFrames.

Comment: Exactly, I also didn't get whether user is selecting IFrame manually by mouse or a javascript will be there to select it. If it is then their should be logic to select that IFrame

Comment: @Amogh I guess I wasn't clear. The user will select a particular frame the same way you select an element with Chrome Developer Tools. But that's not really relevant to my question as it's just explaining *why* I want to to this. I made some edits to make the question clearer.

Comment: To be more clear, you see how on Chrome DevTools you have a list of frames on the console where you can select in which frame your scripts will run, but you also can select elements on the page? I basically wrote a simple version of DevTools on JavaScript and want to be able to determine which frame on the list of frames in the console correspond to the currently selected iframe (which the user selects visually on the page), and which CefSharp `IFrame` corresponds to the current frame on the console so I run all scripts on this frame.

Comment: @user3813463 Yes, this injected script will add an interface to the page that will let the user select elements visually, like Chrome DevTools, and then after the user selects a particular iframe, he'll press a button that should call a method on my C# code telling it to select that particular frame, so I need a way to go from the JavaScript iframe element to CefSharp IFrame.

Comment: @Juan perfect now this makes a clear picture, you are trying to achieve a DevTools feature where user selects a IFrame from dropdown list and whatever script user executes through console runs on that particular frame only. Difference is rather than displaying IFrames in dropdown and getting selected by user, your injected javascript will tell on which IFrame it needs to be selected and executed

Comment: @user3813463 The difference, to be precise, is that instead of selecting the  frame from a dropdown list, the user will select the frame from the page (same as when you press Ctrl+Shit+C on Chrome DevTools). Once the frame is selected, my JS code will know which iframe element is selected, but I also need to know which CefSharp `IFrame` corresponds to this iframe element.

Comment: @Juan I Got it what you want to, Well rather than finding focused frame I will suggest you to go with "frame finding algorithm" (there nothing like this in actual we hust named it) 1. you check if ID is present if yes then pass that ID to c# and c# will access that frame by using `browser.GetBrowser().GetFrame(id);` 2. (like DevTools) if ID is not present `src` of IFrame can be used. if ID is not there pass src/url of IFrame to c# and in c# check and match URL of all frames. 3. (I am not sure about this just give it a try) passs IFrame DOM index and in c# select frame at that index.

Comment: @Amogh The `id` in `GetFrame` is not the same id as the JavaScript id (note that the C# id is an integer while the JavaScript one is a string). The src approach could work but I could have 2 iframes with the same src (although unlikely). I think one approach might work is if the order on `browser.GetBrowser().GetFrameIdentifiers()` is the same as the one in JS `window.frames` (I don't think this matches the DOM order). This way I could use an index to match them. Problem is I don't have any guarantee the orders will match.

Comment: `GetFrame()` is overloaded method it also accepts String

Comment: @Amogh Yes, the string version takes a frame name, but this also doesn't match the JavaScript name nor id attributes (it sometimes does though, but is unreliable).

Comment: @Juan I still didn't understand why you can't go with `GetFocusedFrame()`, may be I am a slow to grasp something. You just have to tell c# that frame is selected by user then c# will get focused frame by `GetFocusedFrame()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153404/discussion-between-amogh-and-juan).